# Loop to multiple sheets with multiple criteria to get the price

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with several worksheets. The main worksheet is the Data worksheet.
The search criteria are in the Data worksheet B2,C2 and D2.The other sheets are cross tabs in which the prices are located.  The prices I am looking for should be transferred in sheet Data column G2. I stuck with following code.

```
Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim wksData As Worksheet: Set wksData = Sheets("Data")
    Dim lngrow As Long
    Dim lngrow2 As Long
    Dim lngSpalte As Long
    
    For lngrow = 2 To wksData.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        Select Case wksData.Cells(lngrow, 2).Value
            Case "Standard"
                Set wks = Sheets("Standard")
            Case "Express Plus"
                Set wks = Sheets("Express Plus")
            Case "Express Saver"
                Set wks = Sheets("Express Saver")
        End Select
        For lngrow2 = 2 To wks.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
           If Trim(wks.Cells(lngrow2, 2).Value) = Trim(wksData.Cells(lngrow, 3).Value) Then
                For lngSpalte = 2 To 10
                    If Trim(wks.Cells(lngSpalte, 3).Value) = Trim(wksData.Cells(lngrow, 4)) Then
                        wksData.Cells(lngrow, 7).Value = wks.Cells(lngrow2, lngSpalte).Value
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        Next
     Next
```

Is anyone able to help? Thank you!

Comment: Your question, as explained in words, does not match the code you try, so I cannot understand what you try accomplishing, in fact. You say: "The search criteria are in the Data worksheet B2,C2 and D2", but your code iterates on all B:B column, taking the search criteria from there. The rest of the code does not simple match a string. If you are not able to explain (**in words**) what you try accomplishing, we cannot understand what problem you have.  We cannot corelate the question with the code. You do not say anything about the code return. Does it raise an error? If not, what does it wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I am trying to explain it again. The code is running without error message.

Comment: lngrow  is the row with the first criteria, langrow2 is the second and lngSpalte the third. B2 ist the value for the lngrow. C2 is the value for the lngrow3 and D2 for lngSpalte. Maybe I'm getting things mixed up here? Perhaps that is the reason why the code is not working.

Comment: I still do not understand anything, sorry. I cannot help in such circumstances. I understand what your code tries doing, but I have no idea about what you want accomplishing, if you do not explain that and we have to deduce from a not working piece of code.

Comment: I am trying to find the prices for the delivery service listed under Data sheet B2 (e.g. Standard) in the respective table (e.g. Standard). The second criteria is the Zone number from the column C2 (e.g. 3) and the last one is the weight which is D2 (e.g. 25kg).The price sheets always have the same structure. The search criteria in the respective price lists are in column A (weight). The zones in rows B2:P2 and the corresponding prices are in cells B3:P53..I tried to upload two pictures, but unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: Depending on which service is selected in column B, which zone in column C and which weight in column D, the corresponding price is to be determined in column G from the respective price lists. I hope that I have now been able to explain it in a reasonably understandable way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT - based on your sample workbook...

```vb
Sub Tester()
    Dim wksData As Worksheet, wks As Worksheet
    Dim lngrow As Long
    Dim delType, delZone, delWeight, mCol, rv
    Dim rngWts As Range, arrWts, rngZones As Range, i As Long, w As Double
    
    Set wksData = Sheets("Data")
    For lngrow = 2 To wksData.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        
        delType = Trim(wksData.Cells(lngrow, "B").Value) 'use some descriptive variables!
        delZone = wksData.Cells(lngrow, "C").Value
        delWeight = CDbl(Trim(wksData.Cells(lngrow, "D").Value))
        rv = ""  'clear result value
        Select Case delType
            Case "Standard", "Express Plus", "Express Saver"
                
                Set wks = Sheets(delType) 'simpler...
                Set rngWts = wks.Range("A3:A" & wks.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
                arrWts = rngWts.Value
                'loop over the weights data
                For i = 1 To UBound(arrWts, 1) - 1
                    If delWeight >= arrWts(i, 1) And delWeight < arrWts(i + 1, 1) Then
                        Set rngZones = wks.Range("B2", wks.Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)) 'zones range
                        mCol = Application.Match(delZone, rngZones, 0)   'find the matching Zone
                        If Not IsError(mCol) Then                        'got zone match?
                            rv = rngWts.Cells(i).Offset(0, mCol).Value
                        Else
                            rv = "Zone?"
                        End If
                        Exit For 'stop checking weights column
                    End If
                Next i
                If Len(rv) = 0 Then rv = "No weight match"
                
            Case Else
                rv = "Delivery type?"
        End Select
        wksData.Cells(lngrow, "G").Value = rv 'populate the result
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Tim Williams. Until mRw the code runs well. With mRw I get the error 2042 = #N/A. I could see that in the local window.Apparently the matching is not working correctly.

Comment: I see that you're using trim() in your original code - I would instead use VBA to first remove all leading/trailing spaces in your lookup tables, otherwise the `Match()` may fail...

Comment: Can you share a sample workbook with your layout (suitably redacted) ?

Comment: Updated based on your workbook...